definition of differential of exponential map
On a Riemann manifold $(M,g)$ and let $p\in M$, the exponential map is defined as
$$
\exp_p: W_p\to M, \ v\mapsto \gamma_v(1)
$$
where $W_p=\{v\in T_pM, \mid \gamma_v \text{is defined for} t=1\}$ and $\gamma_v$ is a geodesic such that $\gamma_v(0)=p, \dot\gamma_v(0)=v$. My problem is, how is the differential of $\exp_p$ defined? I see that in many books the author just identify $W_p\cong T_pM$ and reguard $T_pM$ as a manifold, then the differential at $0\in W_p$ is $d\exp_{p}\big|_0:T_pM\cong T_0(T_pM)\to T_{\exp_p(0)}M=T_pM$. But $W_p$ is merely a subset of $T_pM$, so strictly it should be $T_0(W_p)\to T_pM$, but $W_p$ is not obviously a submanifold, so what is $T_0(W_p)$?

$W_p\subset T_pM$ is an open subset (though it's not obvious)
